# Expanding animation from center of view using Custom Transition

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to present an view, making it look like its expanding slowly from center of another view. I know i can use `animateWithDuration` and `CGAffineTransformScale`to achieve this. Just trying to find out if there is a better way to do this with custom transitions in iOS 7. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Better than what? If you want to use a custom transition, use a custom transition. This is easy. What's the problem?

Comment: What is your problem? I'm asking how to do this using custom transitions. If you have not understood my concern, don't bother. What was the point in down voting?

Answer (score 0):

What about using UIView's animateWithDuration, i think you can achieve your goal with this.

```
//initial size
viewToExpand.frame= CGRectMake(0,0,0,0);
[viewToExpand setCenter: self.center];
//then expand to mainview's size
[UIView animateWithDuration:3 animations:^{
            //change the viewToExpand's size to your desired maximum size
 }];
```